# Why can't I ask questions?

Tags: bug, asking-questions, rate-limiting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are low-rep users rate-limited when posting questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65423/why-are-low-rep-users-rate-limited-when-posting-questions)

When I try to ask a question on stackoverflow.com it gives me this error:

> users with less than 100 reputation can only post questions every 20 minutes; try again later.

Why?

I want to ask more questions. I am not spamming. Isn't the captcha enough to stop spam?

Comment: Is it honestly that hard to figure it out?

Answer (score 5):

The reason for doing this is not only to prevent spam, *but to prevent poor questions from being asked.*

Now I'm not saying your questions are poor or anything, I'm just saying that we have had problems with new users posting poor questions... and we want to slow them down :)