# Why couldn't this guy post another question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm a little peeved because I solved this guy's problem, but his problems with SO caused him to leave minutes before I posted the solution (as a comment).

https://stackoverflow.com/q/16504192/153285

He says he couldn't post an improved question; why would that be?

Comment: Based on his original question, my diagnosis is laziness (or a question ban due to the downvotes).

Comment: @Asad A question ban due to 5 downvotes, having asked only one question? Sounds excessive, he's just a typical newb. (His user page shows he signed up just 16 minutes before his last activity.) As for laziness, he *wanted* to try again.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha How is he arrogant? He said he can't post another question. You're the one who's arrogant.

Comment: He didn't get a question ban from five downvotes on one question. Assuming that's what he's got, then he's deleted a couple of downvoted questions.

Comment: It looks like he registered to post that question, so he probably doesn't have any deleted questions. I'd be surprised if he were banned.

Comment: maybe he was rate-limited?

Comment: @JeremyBanks Confirmed; no deleted questions, yet.

Comment: Probably hit a quality check and couldn't correct it.

Comment: @Oded what's a quality check?

Comment: @Potato by arrogant I mean "No! You will answer this question, I'm not going to open a new one" some people actually think like that.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Except this OP was the opposite. He presumably wrote a new question and the system wouldn't let him post it. He walked away in disgust and it seems there's no sympathy around here, either.

Comment: (For the quality check, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91253/make-the-sorry-we-cant-accept-this-question-message-more-helpful/91987#91987). If they hit that, then it was not really an improved version of the question?)

Comment: As an aside: people should not post new "improved" questions. Instead, they should edit their original bad question, despite the downvotes.

Comment: @Arjan Yes indeed. But once it's also closed, if the question is rewritten from scratch, it's more expedient to start fresh. The reopening process also isn't very transparent for a newbie.

Comment: No one really explained to this user what he needs to do to create a good post. We should all remember that we were new once and may not have written the best questions. Instead, a group of folks jumped down his throat. Maybe we'd get better results if someone had explained to the user that he should describe the problem in the body of the post.  We're really good at telling people what *not* to do, but I see very few people telling folks how to post the right way. Explaining the right way to post has better results than telling people what they're doing wrong. Hope this helps!

Comment: @MadaraUchiha You seem pretty quick to jump from "he said he can't post a question" to "he's a lazy ahole". That's ... not the best attitude to have going into dealing with a first question from a new user. For the record, he is *not* question-blocked; and if your approach usually is "he should figure it out or leave", I hope you don't interact with brand new users often. Or if you do, I hope you take [jmort253's advice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179883/why-couldnt-this-guy-post-another-question#comment545158_179883) to heart. It's pretty spot on.

Comment: @Anna I do apologize for not reading deeper. I automatically assumed that it's either question ban out quality block, both of which aren't really worth the attention unless OP doors real effort to correct himself. But you are correct, I apologize.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Thank you. I do appreciate that it can be challenging to keep a certain perspective when you come across piles and piles of low quality stuff every day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's impossible to tell for sure short of asking for clarification, which we can't do now that the question has been deleted. (And it's not really worth undeleting it just to ask.)

There are a number of checks that user could've run across:

- [the automatic quality ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers): not an issue in this case;
- [the questions-per-day rate limit](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/): doesn't apply unless he's coming from a very common shared IP;
- [the posts-from-new-users rate limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65423/why-are-low-rep-users-rate-limited-when-posting-questions): may or may not be an issue here, also depending on the IP he's coming from. The comment saying he couldn't post another question was left about 17 minutes after he posted the question, so maybe this is it;
- [the "quality standards" check](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards): very plausible that he hit that.

There may be some other options as well, but those are the major ones. The answer still amounts to "we don't know".

In closing, I'd like to draw extra attention to [jmort253's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179883/why-couldnt-this-guy-post-another-question#comment545158_179883):

> No one really explained to this user what he needs to do to create a good post. We should all remember that we were new once and may not have written the best questions. Instead, a group of folks jumped down his throat. Maybe we'd get better results if someone had explained to the user that he should describe the problem in the body of the post. We're really good at telling people what not to do, but I see very few people telling folks how to post the right way. Explaining the right way to post has better results than telling people what they're doing wrong. Hope this helps!

I hope that when (or if) this user tries to post another question that it goes better for them, but if it doesn't that somebody will take a bit of time to explain how to be better at asking on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks… the quality standards check is quite likely it. (But that does imply the edited post was poorer than the original, which is a little odd.) It looks like he came back a couple hours after the post was deleted, which means he never saw the solution I posted in the comments. So it goes.